# Add placeholder without access to input filed

Tags: css, angular

Is there way to enable a placeholder in out of scope component?

Example:

```
<foreign-component [config]="someConfig" placeholder="somePlaceholder"></foreign-component>
```

Inside `<foreign-component>` there is deep-nested `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the parent component will send the placeholder to the foreign-component via input. Then the foreign-component itself will set the incoming placehodler to the input tag

```
<foreign-component [placeholder]="placeHolderText"></foreign-component>
```

in the .ts:

```
public placeholder: string = 'My placeholder text';
```

Now in your foreign-component template

```
... your code ...

<input [placehodler]="placeholder" .... more code
```

foreign-component ts

```
@Input() placeholder: string;
```

PS: I've created a StackBlitz for you to check the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnbx6l?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the title says, that I do not have access to that component, it is like a package, so I cannot add there anything

Comment: Oh, then you are limited by the package. It is out of your scope

Comment: yes that is right definition, I'll edit my post